# Creating MMC Snap-Ins for console application and windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, remoting, mmc, mmc3

Hi guys I need to have a standard management gui ( look and feel ) and lately I've been looking into mmc. Msdn and other free tutorials provides the installation and simple implementation of a snap in.

I'm confused right now on how I can integrate it with my production applications( console and windows service ). Do I need to set a communication protocol for my snap in and other applications?  I'm thinking of doing some classic remoting or via wcf for the communication protocol but not pretty sure if that should be my road map.

What I needed is a sample demo or tutorial that implements a snap-in  communicating with a working console application or a windows service. If anyone can give some pointers on how to do it or some real life implementation  is very much appreciated.

Comment: Here are a couple interesting pages: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3909/Remoting-Management-Console and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/419660/IP-Watchdog-Simple-Windows-Service-Written-in-Csha HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMC does not dictate how you talk to your code. It is only the presentation layer. You can do pretty much anything you like (as long as you are well behaved in terms of not blocking the UI thread), you can do network calls, ADSI, RPC, WCF, COM, Win32,....

We using the ironring C# library instead of the mmc3 c# support; it is more stable (and works with older mmc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , now I know that I'm doing the right thing. Can you give a link going to site of the library you're using?I'm going to look into it also. Thanks.